# Creating a jQuery XP bar

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-widgets

I want to create an XP bar as you see in many games showing the progress from one level to another in a game.

I cannot find any widgets people have already created - but thought using jQuery might make my life easier.

Has anyone done this, or have any idea how to do it.

I found http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar which is a starting point, but i want to have a more complete actual XP bar with things like numbers around it, etc etc etc.

Is this possible - can anybody help!?

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you need help with?

Comment: Well, would i extend the progressbar object in javascript, to include my extra content i want like, nice little colours which reflect where your xp is, and text alongside the bar which shows how much xp you actually have etc,....i just dont know how to create one.

Comment: Nothing -because I do not know how to do any of the things I am suggesting!

Comment: I think a good starting place for you would be to use javascript or jquery to manipulate a HTML element on the page and change it's text. That is the basis of everything you have to do here.

Comment: I dont need to update on the fly, and even if i did that infrastructure is in place, numbers increasing as numbers, but now i want numbers turned into a gui xp bar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I simply made a

element which incremented via jQuery and after that linked into a preexisting javascript xp bar